# SystemVerilog a series of delayed assignment

Tags: model, verilog, variable-assignment, timing, behavior

I'm new for Verilog syntax.
Is there any way to make this assignment as single line in SystemVerilog?

For example, sequential bit assignments is given by

```
                out <=1 
                out <= #1 0;
                out <= #2 1; 
                out <= #3 0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single line but you could use a loop to invert the signal at fixed intervals. For example, I often generate a test bench clock using a forever loop like this:

```
initial begin
    out = 1'b1;
    forever #1 out = ~out;
end
```

You could replace the forever loop with a for loop if you only wanted to generate a small number of pulses:

```
initial begin
    out = 1'b1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) begin
        #1 out = ~out;
    end
end
```